# Write a function to remove everything in the global environment

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function to remove everything from the global environment. But `rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))` is not working within a function.

```
z = 1:10

clean.mem <- function() {
  rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
  }
clean.mem()
```

I also try:

```
clean.mem <- function() {
  rm(list = ls(all = TRUE), envir = globalenv(), pos = globalenv())
  }
```

but it still fails. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need `envir = globalenv()` inside `ls`, too.

```
clean.mem <- function() {
  rm(list = ls(all = TRUE, envir = globalenv()), envir = globalenv())
  }

x <- 1:4
.x <- 2:5
clean.mem()
ls()
#character(0)
```